# Appropriate word for previous and previous to previous

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

i have worked for 2 companies  named Y and Z and currently working with X company.How i can pass this information to other in English -

(1) My current company is X.

(2) My previous company was Y.

(3) My previous to previous company was z.

I know somewhere corrections are required in above expressions so please correct me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You first sentence can be rearranged to cover (1), (2), and (3), like this:

> I am currently working with *X Company*. I previously worked for *Y Company*. Before that, I worked for *Z Company*.

You can expand them by filling in more details to make your writing flow better:

> I am currently working with *X Company*. I previously worked for *Y Company* on some exciting projects, [...]. Before that, I worked for *Z Company*, where I developed [...].